# How to use Worklight JMS adapter to connect to WebSphere MQ

Tags: jms, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-mq, worklight-adapters

I have followed the steps given in this link to get the JMS adapter working, but couldn't get it working

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_connecting_jms_adapters_to_websphere_mq.html

I am using Worklight Devlopment Server v6.2, and I am trying to connect to WebSphere MQ (both worklight & mq are on the same machine), would jms adapter work with this setup ? Are there any other configurations that needs to be done for this to work

below are the adapter entry combinations that I have tried

Combination 1:

```
  <namingConnection url="file:/C:/K5/JNDI_DIR/" 
          initialContextFactory="com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory"/>

  <jmsConnection connectionFactory="TESTJMSCONNFAC" />
```

Error message: *[ERROR   ] FWLSE0005W: JMS connection exception received: null. Closing the connection.*

Combination 2:

```
  <namingConnection url="tcp://localhost:1414" 
          initialContextFactory="com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory"/>

  <jmsConnection connectionFactory="MQConnectionFactory" />
```

Error message: *[ERROR   ] FWLSE0005W: JMS connection exception received: tcp://localhost:1414. Closing the connection.*

Configuration Info below:

[image]

Comment: Your combination 1 looks correct. Can you post parts of the implementation code that show where you are specifying the destination?

Comment: In the readMessage procedure, 


 
     var result = WL.Server.readSingleJMSMessage({
         destination: "JMSDestination",
         timeout: 60
        });

Comment: Have tried this also,
var result = WL.Server.readSingleJMSMessage({
     destination: "dynamicQueues/JMSDestination",
     timeout: 60
    });

Comment: Can you check your liberty server stack trace? There may also be a stack trace there associated with the error.

Comment: these are the messages in the logs when I invoked the procedure,

[9/28/14 15:07:32:935 SGT] 00000015 com.ibm.ws.config.internal.xml.XMLBundleProcessor            A CWWKG0018I: The server configuration was not updated. No functional changes were detected.
[9/28/14 15:07:39:881 SGT] 00000151 com.worklight.adapters.jms.JMSConnectionManager              E FWLSE0005W: JMS connection exception received: null. Closing the connection.

Comment: I found the above messages in messages.log file, which is at Workspace\WorklightServerConfig\servers\worklight\logs. Couldn't find trace log

Comment: Everything looks good based on what I've seen here. I think you should open a PMR to get direct support.

Comment: @aryanRaj_kary, Did you open a PMR?

Comment: I didn't open a PMR, I was trying this on my machine, was learning the concepts, but no luck so far couldn't get it working.

Comment: @aryanRaj_kary, Any updates about this question?

Comment: Still the same, no luck.

Comment: Try on a production-grade worklight (not dev). The studio server does not support acting as a JMS provider.

Comment: Maybe this link would help:
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/04_05_JMS_adapter_-_Communicating_with_JMS.pdf